# could not find stored proc

Tags: sql-server-2008, excel, ado, vba

I'm trying to run a stored proc on a 2008 sql server. I have created the one-line proc, dbo.sp_test_proc. 
I can run the proc via EXEC on the server, and it returns. 
However, when I try to run via ADO in an excel/vba, I get the error message 'could not find the stored procedure sp_test_proc. 
I can run sys schema stored procs via ADO, but not any dbo ones. I am in the role db_owner, and vba code is running under the same windows user that created the stored proc in server management studio. 
Anyone got any ideas? I am stumped.

```
Sub storedProcedure()
'This sub-routine defines an ADOBD command to return variables to VBA from SQL Stored Procedures.
'The ADODB command executes a Stored Procedure on the SQL Server (cmd.CommandText = [Stored Procedure Name])
'Input requirements from the Stored procedure are declared as variants at the start of the sub-routine.

Dim cnt As ADODB.connection
Dim rst As ADODB.recordset
Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
Dim stCon As String         'SQL Connection string
Dim stProcName As String    'Stored Procedure name

'Declare variables for Stored Procedure
Dim myVariable As Variant
Dim myReturn As String

'Set ADODB requirements
Set cnt = New ADODB.connection
Set rst = New ADODB.recordset
Set cmd = New ADODB.Command

'Define database connection string
stCon = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;"
stCon = stCon + "Data Source=myserver;"
stCon = stCon + "Initial Catalogue=Mmydb;"
stCon = stCon + "Integrated Security=SSPI;"
stCon = stCon + "Persist Security Info=True;"

'Open database connection
cnt.ConnectionString = stCon
cnt.Open

' Defines the stored procedure commands
stProcName = "dbo.my_sp"                'Define name of Stored Procedure to execute."
'stProcName = "sys.sp_stored_procedures"    'Define name of Stored Procedure to execute.
cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc           'Define the ADODB command
cmd.ActiveConnection = cnt                  'Set the command connection string
cmd.CommandText = stProcName                'Define Stored Procedure to run



'Execute stored procedure and return to a recordset
Set rst = cmd.Execute()
'myReturn = rst.Fields("procedure_name").Value
myReturn = rst.Fields("mycolumn").Value

'Call Sub-Routine_That_Uses_The_Returned_Data
MsgBox (myReturn)

'Close database connection and clean up
If CBool(rst.State And adStateOpen) = True Then rst.Close
Set rst = Nothing

If CBool(cnt.State And adStateOpen) = True Then cnt.Close
Set cnt = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Word of caution: you should **NOT** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedure names; Microsoft reserves that prefix for its own use; change it to something else

Comment: Agreed, was trying just about everything to get it to pick up the stored proc. Have tried with different name.

Comment: Are you sure that "Initial Catalogue=Mmydb" is the right database?

Comment: Found the error. Initial catalogue is the right db, but it should be catalog, rather than catalogue. No error thrown though.

Answer (score 0):

I really want to thank you all as this post helped me to fix the '3 hours issue' why the hel* vba ADODB code doesn't work!

I will just add that in my case it was not working **Set rst = cmd.Execute()**
I've needed to change this to: **Set rst = cmd.Execute(, , adCmdStoredProc)**

Also, I had mistake in: **InitialCatalog=**. Correct one is:**Initial Catalog=** 
In this case the error message was really unhelpful because it was saying:"Could not find stored procedure..."